# How to get the position of an specific li in a ul tag?

Tags: jquery, jquery-hover, onhover

I want to get number of one `li` that I hover on with `jQuery`.
this is my code :

```
<ul>
   <li></li>
   <li></li>
   <li></li> /* I want hover on this element */
   <li></li>
   <li></li>
</ul>
```

I want when hover on certain element in top code get number of all `lies`.... for example in top code I want get 3 (This means that this third element)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this:

```
var number = $(this).index() + 1;
```

**Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rQTgB/)**

The [**.index()**](http://api.jquery.com/index/) starts at 0 so I added +1 because you wanted to start counting from 1.